# Postman Test Array inside nested Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api, postman

I am trying to put assertion inside the postman array. I have try to retrieve array inside array but its having error.

any suggestion will be gently appreciated.

```
{
  "meta": {
    "code": 200
  },
  "data": [
    [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "sdgsdfg",
        "_version": 1,
        "_shards": {
          "total": 2,
          "successful": 1,
          "failed": 0
        },
        "created": true
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "test",
        "_version": 1,
        "_shards": {
          "total": 2,
          "successful": 1,
          "failed": 0
        },
        "created": true
      },

    ]
  ]
}
```

So far I have tried this but its giving error.

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

pm.test("Checking Success Response on Service", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(201);
});

for(var i=0; i< jsonData.data.length ;i++){

    for(var j=0; j< jsonData.data[i].length ;j++){
        console.log(jsonData.data[i].j._index);
    }
}
```

**There was an error in evaluating the test script:  TypeError: Cannot read property '_index' of undefined**

Please let me know what can be done.

Comment: nested array so `jsonData.data[i][j]._index`

Comment: That is working fine. but I do not get the logic here there is 2nd array that is inside first. Also its having total individual objects.

Comment: `jsonData.data[i].j._index` When you say `j`, it takes the `j` literally. You need to say `[j]` so that it can evaluate to the value of j and then search the array.

Comment: So are you telling me it works like matrix?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something a bit more basic to log those values out to the console:

```
jsonData.data.forEach(dataItem => {
    dataItem.forEach(item => {
        console.log(item._index)
    })
})
```

This is just looping over the data array and then looping through the nested array.